# hibernate stop responding after heavy query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Register {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    private Date checked;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private RegisterType tipo;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = String.class)
    @Column(name = "relatedMedia")
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 200)
    private List<String> relatedMedia = new Vector<String>(5);

    private boolean preLiked = false;
    private boolean preCommented = false;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = false, mappedBy = "toUser")
    @OrderBy("quando DESC")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Message> messages = new Vector<Message>(50);
}
```

I've a problem with this entity in my system. Actually the database has 1.5Million saved Registers, all of them has 0 Message and 0 RelatedMedia (juts to be sure the problem isn't with them)

When I try to load all Register.userId from database, the query works fine and very fast.

When I try to load all Registers from database, the hibernate stop responding. 
Running the query in mysql console says that query returned in few milliseconds... but in hibernate the program simple get stucked in some internal code of framework. NO EXCEPTION, NO RETURN, NO LONGER RESPONDING.

Considering that my entity is pretty smaill its primary key plus 2 booleans one int [tipo] and one date... the difference between load just the primary key and all 5 fields shouldn't be so long.

does anyone know what can be the problem? are there any limit for that? is a heap limit? but if is a heap limit why dont i get stackoverflow?

**===================UPDATE======================**
Despite the fact no exception was being thrown, I had great suspects about heap size, so I just adjusted the heap values on jvm and the query worked in less than 10 secs.

The question is why the exception was never thrown? It is a runtimeexception so it should be thrown straight from jvm... does hibernate has a `catch(Exception e)` in loop?

Comment: Enable SQL debug logging and see what Hibernate might be doing?  I'm curious with specfying `SUBSELECT` is the cause.  Have you tried `SELECT` to use the default fetch mode strategy for collections to see if that returns?

Comment: I use SUBSELECT because I prefer one large query than thousands of tiny queries... But as I said there is NO entity in relatedMedia table, nor in Messages table and as both are lazy hibernate even try to fetch them.